# 밭인 and 주장 meaning

Tags: korean-to-english, phrase-request

The sentence is:

> 너한테 필요한 건 키만 크고 얼굴이 여드름 밭인 농구부 주장이 아니야.

According to Naver **밭이다** means to be filtered? Which doesn't really make sense? Or is it like his face was a field of acne?

**주장** also means like, assertion? So I guess I'm just confused about the entire sentence.

Comment: `밭` = (A farmer's) field / `주장` = the captain

Comment: ~밭이다 can mean 'full of ~' and 주장 can mean 'the captain'.

Answer (score 1):

농구부 주장 - basketball team captain

Recall that when turning "is" 이다 into an adjective it becomes 인, so 밭 here is the noun "field".

A translation could be

> What's needed from you is not a tall basketball team captain with a face like a field of acne.

Although I can't imagine what kind of context such a sentence would come up in...